# Implemented line chart using Flutter-charts. X-axis does not rescale

Tags: flutter

In [this code](https://gist.github.com/BitKnitting/6ae571d79cc47302112c375920410bcf) I change the x-axis by incrementing the _counter.

```
  Random random = Random();
    var data = [
      EnergyReading(_counter, random.nextInt(100)),
      EnergyReading(_counter + 1, 42),
      EnergyReading(_counter + 2, _counter),
    ];
```

When _counter gets updated, the x-value updates.  However, the x-axis range starts at 0 instead of _counter.  What I want is a line chart that scrolls to the left as the x-values increment.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

The way I ended up doing this was to use a timeseries chart.  I also set the measureUpperBoundFn and measureLowerBoundFn to constrain the y-axis.